# Pandas find the percentage of overlap and split to train test

Tags: python, pandas, split, training-data, test-data

I am running a ML experiment in python and I am stuck with data that have overlaps.
I am having a dataframe with multiple columns and the rows between entries are to a big extent similar to subsequent rows.

Are there pandas functions that can split my data frame to two sets trying to reduce the overlaps between the two sets, in a sense that the overall overlaps between the two sets will be as small as possible?

Unfortunately I can not share the dataset but if you can pinpoint me to relevant functions that will be enough for me to continue searching and reading.

I would like to thank you in advance for your reply
Regards
Alex

Comment: you can do train_test_split with shuffle param as true but it would not give any  guarantee  of similarity between train and test set

Comment: Try to provide details and some sample desired output